# Why does Tywin Lannister send Tyrion to King's Landing to be Hand of the King instead of himself?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I've read all of the available books in the *A Song of Ice and Fire* series, and I am now watching *Game of Thrones* until Season 3 Episode 2. No spoilers if you can help it.

One thing I don't understand is that after Joffrey beheaded Ned Stark and proves himself to be a terrible king (and his mother Cersei unable to control him), Tywin Lannister sends Tyrion to King's Landing to be Hand of the King.

Of course Tyrion is his son, but Tyrion is obviously not his favorite. So why doesn't Tywin just send himself to be Hand of the King, and instead, prefer to stay at the ruined castle Harrenhal?

Is this decision explained anywhere in the book or in the TV series?

Comment: In a deleted scene, he did order himself back to Kings Landing, but he refused the order, and it's really difficult to win an argument against yourself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's explained in the very episode why Tyrion was sent, because he is family, Tywin's son. And of course he can't send Jaime because he's been captured. Note both Tywin's and Tyrion's first comments in the quote below. Tywin has realised Tyrion is quite good at ruling and King's Landing needs a good ruler at the moment. Tyrion's comment about strategy is also quite telling. He himself isn't the best at it so he wouldn't make much use in battle but Tywin is.

> **Tywin Lannister:** They have my son! Get out, all of you. (to Tyrion) Not you. You were right about Eddard Stark. If he were alive, we could have used him to broker a peace with Winterfell and Riverrun, which would have given us more time to deal with Robert's brothers. But now – madness. Madness and stupidity. I always thought you were a stunted fool. Perhaps I was wrong.
>
> **Tyrion Lannister:** Half wrong. I'm new to strategy, but unless we want to be surrounded by three armies, it appears we can't stay here.
>
> **Tywin Lannister:** No one will stay here. Ser Gregor will head out with 500 riders and set the Riverland on fire from God's Eye to the Red Fork. The rest of us will regroup at Harrenhal. And you will go to King's Landing.
>
> **Tyrion Lannister:** And do what?
>
> **Tywin Lannister:** Rule. You will serve as Hand of the King in my stead. You will bring that boy king to heel, and his mother too, if needs be. And if you get so much as a whiff of treason from any of the rest – Baelish, Varys, Pycelle…
>
> **Tyrion Lannister:** Heads, spikes, walls. Why not my uncle? Why not anyone? Why me?
>
> **Tywin Lannister:** You're my son.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 1 Episode 10, "Fire and Blood"</sub>

It's also worth noting that Tywin *is* Hand of the King at that moment in time. However, he is too busy at war to go back and lead at King's Landing. He was playing to the strengths of his family, Tyrion ruling and himself fighting and being a strategist.

Tyrion's thoughts on the matter are elaborated on a bit more in this scene. He sends Tyrion, and not an uncle of someone else, because Tywin has given up on Jaime. That means Tyrion is now his only son, in his head, and so he needs to rely on him more to carry on House Lannister.

> "More than you know, Father," Tyrion answered quietly. He finished his wine and set the cup aside, thoughtful. A part of him was more pleased than he cared to admit. Another part was remembering the battle upriver, and wondering if he was being sent to hold the left again. "Why me?" he asked, cocking his head to one side. "Why not my uncle? Why not Ser Addam or Ser Flement or Lord Serrett? Why not a … bigger man?"
>
> Lord Tywin rose abruptly. "You are my son."
>
> That was when he knew. You have given him up for lost, he thought. You bloody bastard, you think Jaime's good as dead, so I'm all you have left. Tyrion wanted to slap him, to spit in his face, to draw his dagger and cut the heart out of him and see if it was made of old hard gold, the way the smallfolks said. Yet he sat there, silent and still.
>
> <sub>*A Game of Thrones*, Tyrion IX</sub>

Comment: The question is asking why Tyrion **instead of himself, Tywin**, but this part you've only focused on in one sentence of your answer. The OP doesn't seem to be asking why Tyrion instead of some uncle etc.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The answer to why Tyrion instead of anyone answers why not Tywin as well. I then elaborated further on why he doesn't send himself specifically.

Comment: Tywin's choice makes perfect sense in the on-screen universe. Someone has to go, and he is otherwise occupied. Tyrion is the logical choice because he is family and, despite Tyrion's penchant for self-indulgence, his loyalties and ethics are reliable and predictable - Tywin knows exactly how Tyrion will perform as hand.

Comment: Why can't Tywin plan war from King's Landing and as the Hand if the King?  To me this makes more sense , and gives him more legitimacy to suppress the "rebel"

Comment: @Graviton it’s much harder to fight the enemy if your tactics take weeks to get to the front line. By the time they get there they’d be pointless.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot not too sure about your theory that you need to be at the front line in order to wage an effective war-- Tywin Lannister stays at King's Landing and becomes the Hand of King after the battle at blackwater while he still has to fight off the Stark. Not only that , when he dispatches Tyrion, the Stannis posts a more immediate threat via the sea towards Kings Landing . So why Tywin doesn't fend off Stannis first ?

Comment: @Graviton it’s a war to fight on multiple fronts he can’t be everywhere and he’s an excellent field commander.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a test to see how Tyrion would be in a position of power, unfortunately, in addition to being mean to Pycelle and the other guy in the Gold Cloaks, he just drank with Bronn and f***ed Shae... after the Battle of the Blackwater, Jaime was still lost to Tywin, but he put Tyrion aside anyway, and refused Casterly Rock to Tyrion.

> "You will serve as Hand of the King in my stead. You will bring that boy king to heel, and his mother too, if needs be. And if you get so much as a whiff of treason from any of the rest – Baelish, Varys, Pycelle"

And the conclusion of the conversation is when the two meet again, now Tywin as Hand.

> "I sent you here to advise the king. I gave you real power and authority. You chose to spend your days as you always have, bedding harlots and drinking with thieves."

And there is also Shae, whom Tywin forbade Tyrion to take to court, if I'm not mistaken, he talked about her 4 times during the 2 conversations, but Tyrion didn't get the hint. The last time was...

> "But neither gods nor men will ever compel me to let you turn Casterly Rock into your whorehouse."

Which means that Tyrion also failed the whore's test.